# CSS for specific div with multiple div having same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple div with same class.
When a user taps on one div i have a slidetoggle() in that i have two buttons "accept" and "reject". Now when the user clicks on the accept or rejects i want that specific div to change colour to green or red based on accept or reject.

But when i try to assign the colour all the div change colour.

Is there anyway to change the colour of the specific div.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#one1",function(){
    $("div.comp2").on("tap",function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow", function(){
        $("#accept").on("click",function(){
            $("div.comp2").css("background-color","#22bb45"); 
        });
    });
    });
});
```

Comment: @K.B.M It's right there in the question...?

Comment: Please check out. https://jsfiddle.net/2nd92djt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the event handler you can use the `this` keyword to refer only to the element which raised the event, instead of selecting all of the elements by class. Try this:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#one1",function(){
    $("div.comp2").on("tap", function() {
        var $comp2 = $(this);
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow", function(){
            $("#accept").on("click", function(){
                $comp2.css("background-color","#22bb45"); 
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: There is one more issue..the slide toggle opens for the second div in the same place where it opens for the first div, how to make it open below the 2nd div..thanks.

Comment: We would need to see your HTML for that. I would suggest opening a new question for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#one1",function(){
    $("div.comp2").on("tap",function(){
    var __this = this;
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow", function(){
        $("#accept").on("click",function(){
            $(__this).css("background-color","#22bb45"); 
        });
    });
    });
});
```